# align nodes and labels tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to left align separate tikzpictures. I am generating the markup for these pictures using `R`. There will be more than 500 such pictures; thus, I want to avoid any `subfigure` options. I've tried `align=left`, `baseline`, `text width` and tried many other solutions available on this site, but I can't figure out how to align the first left node of all individual pictures. If the nodes are aligned, then the label text alignment is irrelevant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\threecircles}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle,double,draw=gray,label=below:#1,anchor=west,align=flush left,text width = 0.5em] at (0,0) (first) {};
\node [circle,double,draw=gray,label=below:#2,align=flush left,text width = 0.5em,right=5cm of first] (second) {};
\node [circle,double,draw=gray,label=below:#3,align=flush left,text width = 0.5em, right=5cm of second] (third) {};
\draw [line width=1mm, gray] (first) -- (second) -- (third);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\center
\threecircles{A}{B}{C}\hspace*{\fill}\\
\threecircles{Dasdsadsasa}{Easdsadsad}{Fasdsad}\hspace*{\fill}\\
\threecircles{John Smith}{Craig Smith}{Jenny Smith}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

I get this:[image]

I wish to see all the nodes aligned vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously get the problems partly because the first (and last) labels are of different lengths, which makes the `tikzpicture`s have different widths. One possible workaround would be to set the first and last label in a zero-width box and center the `tikzpicture`s. One problem of this is of course that the first and last label may extend into the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % to indicate text area
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\threecircles}[3]{% <- you need this to avoid a spurious space
\begin{tikzpicture}[circlenode/.style={circle,double,draw=gray,text width=0.5em}]
% note \makebox[0pt][c]{#}
\node [circlenode,label=below:{\makebox[0pt][c]{#1}}]  (first) {};
\node [circlenode,label=below:#2,right=5cm of first] (second) {};
\node [circlenode,label=below:{\makebox[0pt][c]{#3}},right=5cm of second] (third) {};
\draw [line width=1mm, gray] (first) -- (second) -- (third);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\centering
\threecircles{A}{B}{C}

\threecircles{Dasdsadsasa}{Easdsadsad}{Fasdsad}

\threecircles{John Smith}{Craig Smith}{Jenny Smith}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this works. If the text goes into the margins, I will reduce the space between the nodes.