# Format and align arrows as labels in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I'm trying to reproduce the following Ti*k*Z graph:

[image: graph to reproduce]

I managed to create the nodes and the arrows but can't understand how to draw the arrows below the nodes.

This is my result for now with the following code (for the graph on the left):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = center, node distance = 9em, auto, thick]
    \node [circlenode] (a) {$a$};
    \node [circlenode, xshift=+2cm] (b) {$b$};
    \node [circlenode, xshift=+4cm] (c) {$c$};

    \draw [->] (a) edge [] node {} node[] {} (b);
    \draw [->] (b) edge [] node {} node[] {} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: my graph until now]

Are those arrows inserted in a label or using a new `\draw` macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = center, node distance = 9em, auto, thick,>=latex,
circlenode/.style={circle,draw,text width=1em}] % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327060/121799
    \node [circlenode] (a) {$a$};
    \node [circlenode, xshift=+2cm] (b) {$b$};
    \node [circlenode, xshift=+4cm] (c) {$c$};

    \draw [->] (a) edge [] node {} node[] {} (b);
    \draw [->] (b) edge [] node {} node[] {} (c);
    \draw [->|] ($(a.south east)+(1em,-1em)$) -- ($(b.south west)+(-1em,-1em)$);
    \draw [|<-] ($(b.south east)+(1em,-1em)$) -- ($(c.south west)+(-1em,-1em)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about this library. And I can use it also to draw the double arrow in the second example right?

Comment: @Daniele Sure. `    \draw [->] ($(b.south west)+(0,-1em)$) -- ($(b.south east)+(0,-1em)$);
    \draw [<-] ($(b.south west)+(0,-2em)$) -- ($(b.south east)+(0,-2em)$);`

Answer (score 2):

You could align the arrows with the anchors of the nodes and shift the start and end points of the arrows up or down:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum width=5mm]
 \node [circle,draw,label=above:{$X$}] (a) {};
 \node [circle,draw,label=above:{$Y$},xshift=+15mm] (b) {};
 \node [circle,draw,label=above:{$Z$},xshift=+30mm] (c) {};

 \draw [->] (a) -- (b);
 \draw [->] (b) -- (c);

 \draw [->|] ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-3mm]a.east) -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-3mm]b.west);
 \draw [|<-] ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-3mm]b.east) -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-3mm]c.west);
 
 \draw [->] ([yshift=-4mm]b.west) -- ([yshift=-4mm]b.east);
 \draw [<-] ([yshift=-5mm]b.west) -- ([yshift=-5mm]b.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```